# how to restrict a column 1 entry from having duplicate entries in column 2 (postgresql)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Brief explanation:
i have table1 with columns employee_id,month,amount_spent

an employee should have only one entry for one month

```
employee_id  month     amount_spent
E-124        JANUARY   200$
E-124        MARCH      14$
E-78         JANUARY    56$
```

I want to restrict an entry of (E-124,JANUARY,14$) as E-124 already has submitted his expense for the month JANUARY.

Comment: A simple `UNIQUE` index on employee_id and month should do it...?

Comment: CONSTRAINT emp_id_month UNIQUE (employee_id_id, month)
will it work?
can E-124 enter a record for any month except JANUARY and MARCH

Comment: @Hardy: yes, that's how a unique index works. Just try it out.

Comment: you should add month with year too. otherwise it works for only one year.

Comment: Ya ok 
thank u Naresh Chaudhary.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply EXCLUSION Constraint.

Definition:

- Exclusion constraints ensure that if any two rows are compared on the specified columns or expressions using the specified operators, at least one of these operator comparisons will return false or null.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY7(
   employee_id INT NOT NULL,
   month           CHAR(10),
   amount_spent    REAL,
   EXCLUDE USING gist
   (employee_id WITH =,
   month WITH <>)
);
```

Hopefully, it will help for you. :)

Comment: A unique index is enough, no need for an exclusion constraint (granted: a unique constraint is just a special case of an exclusion constraint, but still)